# How to scrape a dynamic web site with python

Tags: python, ajax, dynamic, screen-scraping

I'm starting with scraping, and I'm trying to get started with web scraping that has dynamic content. To start with this, I want to try with this web

I want to pick up the table

Date Tournament Surface Rd Rk vRk Score More DR A% DF% 1stIn 1st% 2nd% BPSvd Time

Comment: If you have started working with Scraping. I would better suggest you to look at : https://scrapy.org/ . Scrapy framework. It will be a good start for you.

And, as @Andre mentioned, you can you use selenium for the dynamic contents.

Answer (score 0):

for scraping a dynamic website I would advise you to read on selenium, to emulate browser interaction and be able to get dynamically changed DOM elements.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

They have some starting examples and there is a an addon for firefox named SeleniumIDE that allows you to generate Tests from which you could start learning how to do what you intend.

https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-pt/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/

The SeleniumIDE not only allows you to create python unittests from it, but also JUnit and other languages.

Here is an example from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
assert 'Yahoo!' in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('p')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys('seleniumhq' + Keys.RETURN)

browser.quit()
```

That allows you to make a search on yahoo and send the query seleniumhq as you would in a browser.

If you wish to retrieve a value, than just use the find_element_by_id , name , etc.. and get its text, html etc..

Another thing, if this is to scrape a large number of DOM pages, Firefox webdriver might not be the best solution. In such case the best option is to be entirely headless, and a webdriver like phantomjs is your best option.

Comment: Any example? Thanks for the advise